# When does Gatsby include a third party library into the client side js bundle?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, bundle, gatsby

In Gatsby I use commonmarkjs to parse markdown content from my CMS and render it as HTML. Here is the code:

```tsx
import React, { ReactNode, Component } from 'react'
import { HtmlRenderer, Parser } from 'commonmark' // <- I import some commonmarkjs classes...

interface Props {
  markdown: string
}

export default class Text extends Component<Props> {
  parsedMarkdown: string

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props)
    const parser = new Parser()
    const renderer = new HtmlRenderer()
    this.parsedMarkdown = renderer.render(parser.parse(props.markdown)) // <- ...and use them here
  }

  render(): ReactNode {
    return (
      <div className="text">
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.parsedMarkdown }} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I run the build task and then I analyze the output with [source-map-explorer](https://github.com/danvk/source-map-explorer#readme). Here is the result:

[image]

You can see that commonmark is included in my bundle. **Why?** I thought Gatsby would be smart enough to only use the lib for building the actual template and not including it into my bundle.

Comment: It seems like you are parsing the markdown on the fly, which is expected behavior. 
Have you tried using [gatsby-transformer-remark](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-transformer-remark/) to convert markdown to HTML during build-time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since React hydrates your components client-side, any code needed to do that is going to be included by default in your Webpack bundle. If you'd like to trim some fat, you can [adjust the Webpack configuration to replace or omit certain libraries](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/), but be aware that the response from the GraphQL query is exported as `page-data.json` ([more info](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2019-06-12-performance-improvements-for-large-sites/)) and you will need libraries that transform it downstream (i.e. inside a component) client side.

If you'd like to convert your Markdown into HTML and then use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` without including the Markdown parser in your component code you can use [`createResolvers`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/#createresolvers-api) to perform this conversion within the GraphQL layer, making the prepared string available in your `page-data.json` and removing the need for the library client-side.

This said, I find using a lightweight JSX-aware Markdown parser like [markdown-to-jsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-to-jsx) (5kb minified) to be a preferable approach that allows for greater flexibility and security client-side (no use of `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`).